# Light Grey Issues

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I am having a problem with one of my web pages that I can't seem to fix, a light grey color appears before the header picture as you can see here: https://victory3d.teachable.com/p/japanese-alley-3d-game-environment-creation:

[image: light gray]

I need to have a white space before the hero header content and so I added this code:

[image: code]

How can I modify it so that grey color doesn't show?

Comment: Have you tried using the browser development tools to see what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Also read this please: [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question. Dont use screenshots to give us textual information. Code is text, not pixels!

Answer (score 1):

in the html there is a div:

```
<div class="course-block block liquid_html odd-stripe" id="block-8017829">
```

it's css is:

```
.course-block.odd-stripe, .block.odd-stripe {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

you will want to change it to:

```
.course-block.odd-stripe, .block.odd-stripe {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the white space, you don't have to add a p tag.
Just remove the paragraph tag you added. Then add some top padding, like 75px to the hero course block.

```
.course-block.even-stripe{ padding-top: 75px; }
```

Adjust the padding accordingly.

Comment: I tried that, but changing the pading top 75px to a higher number, didn't change the size of the white space. It remained the same.